# How to setup a hp deskjet 2320 printer & scanner on ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

I had the hp deskjet 2320 printer & scanner running on Ubuntu 20.04 but i am having problems now with 22.04.2.
I can make a simple print but wanted the scanner to work

below is a copy of what happened in the Terminal. I believe I am root, but the system seems to doubt that ????
Please help.

```
evan@evan-Lenovo-ideapad-110-14IBR:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for evan: 
Hit:1 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease          
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease             
Reading package lists... Done                          
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
29 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
evan@evan-Lenovo-ideapad-110-14IBR:~$ sudo apt upgrade
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
evan@evan-Lenovo-ideapad-110-14IBR:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-ldb:
 python3-ldb depends on libldb2 (= 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.2); however:
  Version of libldb2:amd64 on system is 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1.

dpkg: error processing package python3-ldb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-ldb
evan@evan-Lenovo-ideapad-110-14IBR:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Fetched 110 kB in 2s (59.9 kB/s)      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
28 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
evan@evan-Lenovo-ideapad-110-14IBR:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 python3-ldb : Depends: libldb2 (= 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) but 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
evan@evan-Lenovo-ideapad-110-14IBR:~$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
evan@evan-Lenovo-ideapad-110-14IBR:~$
```

Comment: What did you do, before this happened in the terminal? What package did you install from where?

Comment: Hi Bruni, I did not install any other app or program before working on the Terminal. last install was the normal ubuntu software update, notified by ubuntu.

Comment: You did not run `apt --fix-broken install`as root. the system is right on this one. (so do that first). You have to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` for that. However, I still have not figured out what the above problem has to do with your all-in-one device.

Comment: Hi Bruni, thank you for your teaching. I will try the sudo way and let you know what happens.
i was following this https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-networked-hp-printer-and-scanner-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Hi Bruni,

i have been a bit busy with other things but here we go again. i did the sudo apt --fix-broken install  and got this error message:
dpkg: error processing package python3-ldb (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-ldb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
how do i reinstall python3-ldb ?

Comment: `sudo apt --reinstall install python3-ldb`

Comment: Hi Bruni, Thanx alot. please see my new question re python3 problems, posted 2day.
i havent tried your suggested command.
after reading my new posting please tell me if i should do your command. Too scared to do anything at the moment.

Comment: Hi Bruni, i did the command and no errors !!! I expect problem to have been solved. My other question has been closed but the command were different from yours so i didnt use them.